# Ruby on Rails as_json limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have this "as_json" method in my Post model:

```
def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge(:include => { :comments => { :include => [:user] }, :hashtags => {}, :user => {}, :group => {} }))
end
```

I'd like to set a limit attribute in `:comments` like this:

```
def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge(:include => { :comments => { :include => [:user], :limit => 10 }, :hashtags => {}, :user => {}, :group => {} }))
end
```

but it doesn't work.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have only one possibility.

I suppouse that you have a `has_many :comments` association in your `Post` model

So you can define the next `has_many` association in your `Post` model, something like this:

`has_many :ten_comments, -> { limit(10) }, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: :post_id`

And then you will be able to do this in the `as_json` method:

```
def as_json(options={})
   super(options.merge(:include => { :ten_comments => { :include => [:user] }, :hashtags => {}, :user => {}, :group => {} }))
end
```

Sorry for posting four years later, but I hope that someone find useful your question and this answer.